# How do I unlock new characters in Super Crate Box?

Tags: ios, super-crate-box

The new update for Super Crate Box mentioned that there were now more characters to unlock.

I have been playing for a while now (even before the update) and never unlocked new characters.

What do I have to do to unlock new characters?

Comment: For the new ones, it's [1000 crates and 5000 kills.](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/01/10/super-crate-box-ios-updated-next-update-coincides-with-40-milli/)  I'm pretty sure that the old ones are unlocked by getting high scores of a certain amount in each level.

Comment: Is this question about the PC game, or the ios game?

Comment: @GnomeSlice The iOS game.

Comment: I've unlocked only one character so far, and I've been playing for a couple of days. It's a tricky process, and I really don't have any on-hand info on the correct ways to unlock the characters. However if you have the **new** update, go into stats, and view the area showing the characters and your unlocked weapons you can view the shadows of other characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of the characters currently in Super Crate Box, and how to unlock them (which I've compiled after a fun speedrun through a fresh installation of SCB).

- **Ninja**: Score 20 on Ambush mode
- **Astronaut**: Score 10 on Moon Temple
- **Crocodile**: Score 25 on Construction Yard
- **Robot**: Score 30 on Rocket Silo
- **Piklupu**: Score 35 on Moon Temple
- **Billy** Score 100 points on any map on Normal mode
- **Chicken**: Score 50 points on any map on SFMT mode
- [Halfbot](http://www.halfbot.com/): Kill 5000 enemies in total
- [Vlambeer](http://www.vlambeer.com/): Collect 1000 crates in total
- [Canabalt](http://www.adamatomic.com/canabalt/) (Indie Unlock #1): Score 10 crates by only jumping and running
- [Spelunky](http://spelunkyworld.com/) (Indie Unlock #2): Score 10 on Moon Temple, Ambush mode
- [Meat Boy](http://supermeatboy.com/) (Indie Unlock #3): Die 500 times

For the game to tell you how many crates you have to obtain to unlock the next character, you have to have completed the level-unlocking goal first. For example, in this screenshot, the `Score 30 to unlock a new character` text appears because I have already scored 20 to unlock the Moon Temple (the next stage).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Starkid- killing a golden enemy. Golden enemies are found when they go into the fire pit several times. TIP: go to moon temple with a good weapon and sit on the sides (bottom) until one appears.

Comment: This should probably be added to the chosen answer.

Comment: What does the golden enemy look like @Starkid